# VBA - If scrollbar is changed left or right

Tags: vba, scrollbar

I have a scrollbar in a userform and I would like to run some code if it is shifted left and run some different code if it is shifted right.

Something like this (obviously this doesn't work):

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()

If ScrollBar1 = Left Then

MsgBox "left"

ElseIf ScrollBar1 = Right Then

MsgBox "right"

End If

End Sub
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a module level variable to track the last position and compare it to the current:

```
Private mCurrentScrollPos As Long

Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    If (ScrollBar1.Value > mCurrentScrollPos) Then
        MsgBox "Left"
    Else
        MsgBox "Right"
    End If

    mCurrentScrollPos = ScrollBar1.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store a global variable. Set it when the Userform gets activated. And the do the code

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    If (ScrollBar1.Value > scrollLoc) Then
        MsgBox "Left"
    Else
        MsgBox "Right"
    End If

    scrollLoc= ScrollBar1.Value
end sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    scrollLoc = Me.ScrollBar1.Value 
End Sub
```

And have a global variable

```
private scrollLoc as long
```